# Insert based on two elements existing in a row MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, exists

I'm imagining that this is a simple question, but I'm running into syntax issues I think.

I have a table that has an event ID as primary key(eventID), a device ID that of what triggered the event, and a timestamp of when the event triggered.  I"m processing the mySQL(5.1) elements via C# and command line.

My dilemma is that I have to duplicate/import the database to another database and I am getting duplicate entries due to the eventID being the primary key and it being updated everytime a new record is added automatically.  Changing that isn't an option.  So what I want to do is only insert into the database if my current deviceID+timestamp combination doesn't already exist.

I've found a lot of query examples, but they either throw syntax issues or simply don't work as needed.  In pseudo code this is what I'm looking for..

```
IF timestampToInsert EXISTS WHERE deviceIDtoInsert ALSO EXISTS ON SAME ROW
     UPDATE ROW
ELSE
     INSERT INTO myTABLE (deviceID, timeStamp) VALUES (deviceIDtoInsert, timestampToInsert)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do an "upsert".

In MySQL this is called "[INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)":

```
INSERT INTO myTABLE (deviceID, timeStamp)
VALUES (deviceIDtoInsert, timestampToInsert)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

Note this will only work if you have a unique index on (deviceID,timestamp)